# Use of "switch" in Chrome-app versus in regular webpages

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, google-chrome-app

I have a small web application in html/js which works perfectly if you open it in a regular browser. I wanted to adapt the code to be able to run it like a Chrome app (my first Chrome app, by the way), and I did all the necessary changes according to the documentation I read: I got rid of inline js, downloaded local copies of jquery, replaced the `onclick` with event listeners... Now everything works well inside the Chrome app. There is just one thing that doesn't: a switch selector that updates a variable according to what has been selected in a select list. This works well in the regular webpage, but if you run it inside the Chrome app, it's as if the app is ignoring the switch and never updating the values.

Is there any limitation or anything I should take into account in this case? Can it be possible that I need to structure it in a different way to fit the Chrome app requirements?

The code itself:

In the html file we have a text box, whose value will be modified according to what we select in the list. There is also a second text box disabled that will display the result:

```
<input type="text" class="ctext" placeholder="DJN code" id="code">
<input type="text" class="ctext" id="ft" disabled="true" >
<select id="combobox">
<option value="tiranastockexchange">TIRANA  Tirana Stock Exchange</option>
and so on...
```

in the .js file we have a function which interacts with the select box in the following way:

```
function convert() {

    var str = document.getElementById('code').value
    var root = str.replace(/^.*\/|\.[^.]*$/g, '');
    var djticker= "";   
    var prefix = "";
    var ct = "";
    var notes = "";
    var web = "";
    var ex = document.getElementById('combobox');
    var selex = ex.options[ex.selectedIndex].value; 

switch(selex) {
    case "tiranastockexchange":
    prefix = "aT";
    break;
    //and the rest of cases following the same structure... 
    }
```

After the switch, if I operate with strings and use the value of `prefix`, I am still getting value "" instead of "aT", as if the whole switch is ignored. The following is what comes after the switch, just before closing the function:

```
djticker = prefix+root;

var nfield = document.getElementById("notes");
nfield.value = notes;
var result = document.getElementById("ft");
result.value = djticker;
```

So if the value of `code` is ASDF.AS and in the select box you select the value with the value `tiranastockexchange` , the textbox with the id `ft` should display aTASDF

For that, I have an event listener attached to a button in the html file with the id `convert`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var cf = document.getElementById('convert');

    cf.addEventListener('click', function() {
    convert();
    });
});
```

In the other hand, if you run this very same code in a regular html file, it works perfectly.

What could make the difference? 
Thanks!

Comment: [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378); there's no reason a `switch` statement works differently, something else breaks.

Comment: Need more context for that code.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting read about the XY problem! I am guilty of that sometimes... I will edit my question now with longer context.

Comment: Double-check what the values of `ex`, `ex.selectedIndex`, `ex.options` and `selex` are.

Comment: Once again (within 2 minutes) I am agreeing with Xan: Do exactly as he/she says, and you will find your problem.